# Why is Flask-Blogging returning "forget to specify values" error?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

not sure if this is a flask-blogging issue or something else. I am getting the following when making a post on production server (using nginx) . In development, I am not able to recreate the problem.  I managed to debug a bit on production (it is a pain because I have to restart everything for a new printing of value). I found out that `post_id` is `None` right before url_for() is called at line 248:

```
return redirect(url_for("blogging.page_by_id", post_id=pid,
                                            slug=slug))
```

If it makes a difference, I just made my website use HTTPS a while ago. Though I don't remember if this problem existed before that. I think it did.

```
File "/home/deploy/mywebsite/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1758, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'blogging.page_by_id' with values ['slug']. Did you forget to specify values ['post_id']?
```

Has anyone solved a similar problem? or what is the fastest way to debug this?